# Time-based Trigger to update all records

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, scheduled-apex

If I want to "touch" (save, update) all records once a morning in an object (let's use Account as the example, though it would more likely be in a Custom object), how would someone go about that?  To my understanding, you can use a Workflow now (ENTERPRISE ED) to fire a Trigger.  The main issue is the trigger itself.  I wrote this up to see if it would do the trick (several revisions later).  No go.

```
trigger touchAll_ACCOUNT on Account(before update, before insert) {

List<Account> updateList = new List<Account>();

for(Account accObj : [ SELECT Last_TouchAll__c FROM account WHERE Id != null ]  )
{
    accObj.Last_TouchAll__c = System.now();
    updateList.add(accObj);

    if(updateList.size() >= 199){
        update updateList;
        updateList.clear();
    }
}
if(updateList.size() > 0){ update updateList; }
}
```

The main issue is... this trigger cannot be running each time an Account is edited.  It needs to run ONLY when time-based Workflow runs it.  I purposely did not include any "trigger." references trying to avoid it running each time I touch an Account.  Hrumph.

Ideas??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, I think your case would be better suited to an Apex class (as opposed to Trigger) scheduled with a scheduled job, possibly also incorporating Batch Apex (depending on your volumes). See:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

For documentation about implementing the Schedulable interface and this post here about batch apex:

[How do I convert a method to Batch Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/how-do-i-convert-a-method-to-batch-apex)

Comment: ready or not, scheduled (batch) apex is what you should do in such a scenario. Good luck :)

Comment: No problem...you should give it a try, its the best way to learn