# CPU Limit Exceeded because of nested for loops in apex

Tags: apex

Below code is not working when I add the 1000 active users as per the requirement and giving the CPU exceed limit / Collection size 1,189 exceeds maximum size of 1,000.

I want to change the code to avoid the error.

public void buildQueueInfo(List queues, Map<Id, List> queueIdToMembersMap, List allUsers, Map<Id, User> userMap) {

```
Map<Id, Group> queueMap = new Map<Id, Group>(queues);
// Remove queues that have no users.
queueMap.keySet().retainAll(queueIdToMembersMap.keySet());
Set<Id> usergroupIds = new Set<Id>();
for(List<GroupMember> queueMembers: queueIdToMembersMap.values()) {
    for(GroupMember gm: queueMembers) {
        usergroupIds.add(gm.UserOrGroupId);
    }
}
Map<Id, User> allUsersMap = new Map<Id, User>(allUsers);
allUsersMap.keySet().removeAll(userGroupIds);
List<User> nonUsers = allUsersMap.values();
for(Group queue : queueMap.values()) {
    populateQueueInfo(queue, queueIdToMembersMap.get(queue.Id), nonUsers, userMap);   
}
```

}

public void populateQueueInfo(Group theQueue, List currentMembers, List nonMembers, Map<Id, User> userMap) {
queueList.put(theQueue.Id, new QueueInfoWrapper(theQueue, currentMembers, nonMembers, userMap));
}

Comment: Your code example is incomplete, what does method `populateQueueInfo` do?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, "populateQueueInfo" method call the wrapper calls, and below is the populate queinfo,

public void populateQueueInfo(Group theQueue, List<GroupMember> currentMembers, List<User> nonMembers, Map<Id, User> userMap) {
        queueList.put(theQueue.Id, new QueueInfoWrapper(theQueue, currentMembers, nonMembers, userMap));
    }

Comment: On Salesforce, the general solution to doing a lot of work is to break the work up into multiple pieces as each transaction has tight limits. See e.g. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/how-do-i-convert-a-method-to-batch-apex.

Comment: Hi, Batch job is not required here, We are populating the 1000 users in the VF page. So, I need a help on how to avoid the CPU exceed limit with my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, something to clear up:

```
//To Reduce heap size
queues=null;
```

No, this has no impact on heap size, as you're only holding a reference to an object, not an entire copy of the object itself. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/260304/2984) I wrote on that topic that may be illuminating.

To get to the meat of the problem, we have a few problems in this code. Mostly that (a) you're doing more work than you need to by not filtering the list of queues that are not in the queueIdToMembersMap before processing, and (b) you're not utilizing some library functions that you can use to improve performance drastically.

Here, I can quickly create a Map, and filter out all Queues that won't need any processing, as they have no group members:

```
Map<Id, Group> queueMap = new Map<Id, Group>(queues);
// Remove queues that have no users.
queueMap.keySet().retainAll(queueIdToMembersMap.keySet());
```

This is a lot better than:

```
for(GroupMember queue: queues) {
  if(queueIdToMembersMap.containsKey(queue.Id)) {
```

Once we have this new collection, we can get the UserOrGroupId values more efficiently:

```
for(Group queue : queuesMap.values()) {
    for(GroupMember gm : queueIdToMembersMap.get(queue.Id)){ 
        usergroupIds.add(gm.UserOrGroupId);  
    }
}
```

Similarly, your entire second nested loop can be trivialized to:

```
Map<Id, User> allUsersMap = new Map<Id, User>(allUsers);
allUsersMap.keySet().removeAll(userGroupIds);
List<User> nonUsers = allUsersMap.values();
```

Or, we can even optimize the first loop further:

```
for(List<GroupMember> queueMembers: queueIdToMembersMap.values()) {
    for(GroupMember gm: queueMembers) {
        usergroupIds.add(gm.UserOrGroupId);  
    }
}
```

This results in final code that looks something like:

```
public void buildQueueInfo(List<Group> queues, Map<Id, List<GroupMember>> queueIdToMembersMap, List<User> allUsers, Map<Id, User> userMap) {
    Map<Id, Group> queueMap = new Map<Id, Group>(queues);
    // Remove queues that have no users.
    queueMap.keySet().retainAll(queueIdToMembersMap.keySet());
    Set<Id> usergroupIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(List<GroupMember> queueMembers: queueIdToMembersMap.values()) {
        for(GroupMember gm: queueMembers) {
            usergroupIds.add(gm.UserOrGroupId);
        }
    }
    Map<Id, User> allUsersMap = new Map<Id, User>(allUsers);
    allUsersMap.keySet().removeAll(userGroupIds);
    List<User> nonUsers = allUsersMap.values();
    for(Group queue : queueMap.values()) {
        populateQueueInfo(queue, queueIdToMembersMap.get(queue.Id), nonUsers, userMap);   
    }
}
```

---

I've seen your comment about the "1,428 exeeds maximum size of 1,000." This problem has nothing to do with heap limits or CPU limits, but rather that you can't display lists of larger than 1,000 items in Visualforce. If you don't need DML operations, set the page to read-only mode:

```
<apex:page controller="myController" readOnly="true" ...
```

Which relaxes this limit from 1,000 to 10,000, but restricts DML operations.

If you need DML operations, you need to create a nested list of results and iterate over chunks of data. I thought I'd written an answer of this type previously, but I couldn't find it, so I present [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/40302/2984) to you.

The general idea is that you create a top-level collection, then nest it. I'm copy-pasting the original source from that answer for you:

```
public class MultiExample
{
  public List<MultiWrapper> wraps{get; set;}

  public MultiExample()
  {
    wraps = new List<MultiWrapper>();
    wraps.add(wrap);
    MultiWrapper wrap = new MultiWrapper();
    for (Account acc: [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 3000])
    {
      if (wrap.size() == 1000)
      {
        wrap = new MultiWrapper();
        wraps.add(wrap);
      }
      wrap.addAcc(acc);
    }
  }

  public class MultiWrapper
  {
    public List<Account> accs{get; set;}

    public MultiWrapper()
    {
      accs = new List<Account>();
    }

    public void addAcc(Account acc)
    {
      accs.add(acc);
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
<apex:repeat value="{!wraps}" var="wrap">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrap.accs}" var="{!acc}">
    <apex:column>
      <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Id}" />
    </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:repeat>
```

As you can see, a top-level wrapper breaks up the items into groups of 1,000, thus providing a nested loop that supports up to 1,000,000 rows, of which you'll reach other limits far before you break this one.

Comment: Hi, Thanks alot for detail explanation and I have tried with your code and but currently i'm getting the error "Row with duplicate Id at index: 1385" at the line of below code at "removeAll". Pls do help me. thanks in advance.

 Map<Id, User> allUsersMap = new Map<Id, User>(allUsers);
    allUsersMap.keySet().removeAll(userGroupIds);
    List<User> nonUsers = allUsersMap.values();

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, "allusers" have the duplicate users.... my requirement is to fetch all the duplicate users. Can you tell me how we can fix?

Comment: @JagadeeshM Why are there duplicate users in the list?

Comment: As per my requirement, First it will fetch all profile related users and public group of users, see below lines of code which call the buildQueueInfo method..

/**************************/


 agentList = new UserDataAccessor().queryAgentsBasedOnProfile(PROFILE_NAMES);
            agentList.addAll(new UserDataAccessor().queryAgentsBasedOnPublicGroup(PUBLIC_GROUP_API_NAMES));

 buildQueueInfo(allGroups, mapGroupMembers(getGroupIds(allGroups)), agentList, mapUsers(agentList));

Comment: @JagadeeshM I would consider consolidating the duplicates before passing in to your method. Instead of `agentList`, use a map: `Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>(new UserDataAccessor().queryAgentsBasedOnProfile(PROFILE_NAMES));
userMap.putAll(new UserDataAccessor().queryAgentsBasedOnPublicGroup(PUBLIC_GROUP_API_NAMES));
List<User> agentList = userMap.values();
buildQueueInfo(allGroups, mapGroupMembers(getGroupIds(allGroups)), agentList, mapUsers(agentList));`

Comment: Hi Sfdcfox, You are awesome, Now im not getting the duplicate error but My VF page is not loading the above 1000 active users and giving the exception as now  "Collection size 1,189 exceeds maximum size of 1,000."

Comment: @JagadeeshM You still need to either add `readOnly="true"` to your page, or use the nested loop structure mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Finding all of the users who are *not* members of each group is inherently somewhat expensive, but you're doing it in a way that is very inefficient. You're also showing us only portions of your code, so the remainder may be heavily impacting this transaction-wide limit as well.

The core problem shown here is that you are iterating triply, for something like an O(N^3) complexity.

```
        for (Group queue : queues) {
            for (User u : allUsers) {
                    for (GroupMember gm : gmList) {
                    }
                }
            }
```

One clear optimization would be to preprocess each list of `GroupMember` records into a `Set<Id>`. Then, you can check whether each User is a member with a constant-time call to `Set#contains()` instead of a third nested `for` loop.

It's also possible that building a `Set<Id>` of `Users` (once, outside the loop) and using Set intersection to build the list of users that aren't members of each group could further increase performance, rather than iterating. You'd need to benchmark to determine if that were successful.

That said, I suspect that this whole design has a lot of built-in inefficiency that I don't see enough information to comment on. The optimization above might or might not be sufficient to make it run within the transaction limit.

Comment: I tried with adding sets & maps still I'm getting the error "Collection size 1,428 exceeds maximum size of 1,000." with modified code(added code above section ). Thanks!!